# How to increase screen resolution of Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: virtualbox, display, resolution

I tried  to increase the screen resolution of Ubuntu Desktop from the `Display -> Resolution`, but the Apply button is  not displayed (it's not on zoom), but the fonts are so big, I can't access the apply button that will effect the change of screen resolution.[Picture of Apply Buttion Not Displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUqEv.png)

Comment: Why not using xrandr?

Comment: You have a [virtualbox] tag, but no description of your setup.  Are you asking how to make the VM window bigger, or how to set the monitor to a higher resolution?

Comment: `how to set my ubuntu to a higher resolution?`. it's currently stuck on 800 X 600 and I can't increase it because the `Apply button` to effect screen resolution changes is not displayed. I don't know how to zoom out or reduce font size so that the apply button will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to click on the top of the Ubuntu desktop settings window, then drag it to the left so that I can see the Apply button. [Ubutu Desktop At A Bigger Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew4Zx.png)